# Install php without httpd on CentOS 7

Tags: php, nginx

I have nginx installed, and I want to install php, but when I install php with `yum install php`, it requires httpd. Is there a way I can install php without installing httpd?

Comment: google ... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call (skip `sudo` when calling under `root`)

```
$ sudo yum install php
```

`yum` does want to install `httpd` (Apache web-server) as a dependency. In your case, since you are planning to use `nginx` you definitely do not need `httpd`. In order avoid `httpd` installation, but still have a working `php` call

```
$ sudo yum install php-fpm php-common php-cli
```

Answer (score 3):

With nginx you should use `php5-fpm`:

```
yum install php5-fpm
```